# view doesn't get copied

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsview, nscoding

I have a view that contains some objects like this (the green area is my view): 
[image]

Every time I press "item" a new color object gets added to this row of views, I want the "row" button to copy this row as it is and place it above this row when pressed, so I have two (or multiple) rows on top of each other. I made the action for row button like this:

```
    let hc = contentView1
    hc?.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 0, y: (positionY*50)))
    positionY += 1

    contentView2?.addSubview(hc!)
```

but every time I press that button, the same row just moves and does not copy, like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add your code for the item button?

Comment: hey :) thanks for the edit but you placed the images in place of each other.
button has no code its just a NSButton

Comment: i added my xcode project so they can see.its gone now !!

Comment: Never mind, I don't think you need it. Can you just add what contentView1 and contentView2 are referring too?

Comment: It looks like the issue is that you are creating a new view that is equal to the view you want to copy. However, NSViews are reference types, not value types. So editing one view will edit the other.

Comment: these are two `NSView`s that i've created `contentView1` is the view that my objects are placed in (its the row of color objects), and `contentView2` is the view i want to add multiple copies of `contentView1` in it on top of each other and subview it to mu view

Comment: heres the link to the project in case [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64067896/infinite_ubject_test.zip)

Answer (score 0):

A view can have one superview and each time you add a view to a superview, it is removed from its previous superview. `NSView` doesn't implement the `NSCopying` protocol so you can't copy a view by calling `copy`. Search SO for 'copy NSView'.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is that you are creating a new view that is equal to the view you want to copy. However, NSViews are reference types, not value types. So editing one view will edit the other.

`NSView` luckily implements the `NSCoding` protocol, so you can duplicate the view like this:

```
let archivedView = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(contentView1)
let hc = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(archivedView)
```

And then do the rest:

```
hc?.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 0, y: (positionY*50)))
positionY += 1
contentView2?.addSubview(hc!)
```

Comment: `unarchiveObjectWithData` gives error `use of unresolved identifier`

Comment: Double check the code. I had forgot to include `NSKeyedArchiver`.

Comment: yea this time it gives the error : type 'NSKeyedArchiver' has no member 'unarchiveObjectWithData'

Comment: now i get my rows but they are empty : [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Xf6zv.png)

Comment: Are the blocks not subviews of contentView1?

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of after you've add a block to the row and then after you press the row button?

Comment: its the same rows are empty no matter how many times i press item button

Comment: Oh so now item isn't adding?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense since it's not really related to this part of the code...

Comment: it seems no matter that i archive the contentView1 itself or its subviews that are the color objects the subviews get missing!! strange

Comment: I've had some search and someone suggested that the if the view is stored in a nib it can be copied , but I don't know how to store it in a nib!!